# Modal content not visible in React modal

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, modal-dialog

I created a modal component in react, but it only shows the backdrop and not the main content of the modal. In the component tree, the component has a height of 0px. I increased the height but still, it is 0 only. This modal component works when used on some empty window, but not when there is already a lot of content on the window. Is it regarding the z-index?

Following is the code for Modal component:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
 function Pay(props) {
 return (
    <div>
     <div className="backdrop" onClick={props.onConfirm}></div>
     <div className="modal">
       <header className="header">
         <h2>Payment Section</h2>
       </header>
       <div className="content">
         <p>lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
            lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
            lorem ipsum doolr sit amet
         </p>
       </div>
       <footer className="action">
         <button onClick={props.onConfirm}>Pay</button>
       </footer>
     </div>
    </div>
  );
}
export default Pay;
```

The CSS file:

```
.backdrop {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: 200;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}

.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 20vh;
  left: 5%;
  height:400px;
  width: 90%;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 1rem;
  border-radius: 14px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  z-index: 3000;
}


.header {
  background: #4f005f;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.header h2 {
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
}

.content {
  padding: 1rem;
}

.actions {
  padding: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

This is where I call the Modal:

```
function Navigate(props){
  const [show,setShow]=useState(false);

  function pinch(){
    console.log("info from navigation");
    setShow(true);
  }
  function hidePay(){
    setShow(false);
  }
  return(

    <div className = "container1" >
      {show && <Pay onConfirm={hidePay}/>}
      <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
        <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul className="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li className="nav-item doosri">
              <i className="fas fa-search fa-1x"></i>
            </li>

            <li className="nav-item doosri">
              <button onClick={pinch}><i className="fas fa-shopping-cart fa-1x"></i></button>
            </li>

          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  );
}
```

EDIT: It runs when modal's display is set to block.

Comment: Right click on the screen and inspect it in the Developers tab. If you can find it in the inspector section, then you can also see it's CSS and maybe get more information on what is happening. What have you tried to fix this? Maybe making the modal's `position: "absolute"` instead (or visa versa, making the backdrop `position: "absolute"`) and see if that changes anything. Having a `fixed` position inside another `fixed` position element could cause issues.

Comment: @lua_python_java Tried to set modal's position: absolute, nothing happened. Also, it works on an empty window but not on one which already has content.